# How can I pull data from multiple files in Excel using Visual Basic?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel problem that should hopefully be quite easy (logic-wise), but my knowledge of Visual Basic is very limited. I have a few folders with about 30 .xlsm files in them each (each file represents a day). In sheet 13 and 14 of each file are time sheets with two pieces of information that I require (sheet 13 being day shift, sheet 14 being nightshift). Column A has employee names, and column I has vehicle number. What I need to do is extract the name of the employee that was using vehicle number MT332.

For example, let's say this is one of the sheets from one of the files:

```
  Row A:                            Row I:
Doe, John                           MT426
Smith, Jim                          MT856
Richard, Greg                       MT332
Parson, Fred                        MT265
```

I would need to extract the name 'Richard, Greg' from the sheet on the file into a list on a separate spreadsheet. The list will looks something like this:

```
       Drivers for MT332
    Days               Nights
Richard, Greg       Hamill, Susan
Lunz, Trent         Forter, Heath
    ...                  ...
```

Where the Days column comes from sheet 13, and the Nights column comes from sheet 14 on each file.

Please try your best to guide me; I know VERY little of VB syntax!

Thank you!

(Note: these names aren't real)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

1. Open all your workbooks that contain your driver data
2. Now open a new workbook, paste this code, and hit run

The code loops through all the workbooks, grabs the data, and adds it to the relevant column in your active workbook.

```
Sub GetMT332Drivers()
    Dim wbk As Workbook, cl As Range

    Range("A1") = "Drivers for MT332"
    Range("A2") = "Days"
    Range("B2") = "Nights"

    For Each wbk In Workbooks
        If wbk.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            For Each cl In wbk.Worksheets("Sheet13").Range("I2:I" & wbk.Worksheets("Sheet13").Range("I1").End(xlDown).Row)
                If cl = "MT332" Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1) = cl.Offset(0, -8)
                End If
            Next cl

            For Each cl In wbk.Worksheets("Sheet14").Range("I2:I" & wbk.Worksheets("Sheet14").Range("I1").End(xlDown).Row)
                If cl = "MT332" Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1) = cl.Offset(0, -8)
                End If
            Next cl
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```